# clearCache in pyspark without SQLContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Considering the pySpark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext) for `SQLContext` says "As of Spark 2.0, this is replaced by SparkSession."

How can I remove all cached tables from the in-memory cache without using `SQLContext`?

For example, where `spark` is a `SparkSession` and `sc` is a `sparkContext`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
SQLContext(sc, spark).clearCache()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `clearCache` is available elsewhere except `SQLContext` in pyspark. The example below create an instance using `SQLContext.getOrCreate` using an existing SparkContext instance:

```
SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc).clearCache()
```

In scala though there is an easier way to achieve the same directly via SparkSession:

```
spark.sharedState.cacheManager.clearCache()
```

One more option through the catalog as Clay mentioned:

```
spark.catalog.clearCache
```

And the last one from Jacek Laskowski's gitbooks:

```
spark.sql("CLEAR CACHE").collect
```

Reference: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-caching-and-persistence.html

Comment: Thanks, this led me to figure out that accessing the underlying Java SparkSession from pySpark can do the same thing `spark._jsparkSession.sharedState().cacheManager().clearCache()`

Comment: you are really keen to optimize your code as much as possible :)

Comment: I also found that `spark.catalog` appears to be the replacement for `SQLContext` although not well documented in 2.2.0.  So, `spark.catalog.clearCache()` also clears the cache.

Comment: ok I came across that as well from the documentation I concluded that is used mostly for the interaction with Hive, storing table information etc. Well done!